# Read binary file and count specific number c++

Tags: c++, file, count, binary

Hey everyone I've been looking everywhere for insight on how to do this particular assignment. I saw something similar but it didn't have a clear explanation. I'm trying to read a bin file and count the number of times a specific number appears. I saw examples of this using a .txt file and it seemed very straight forward using getline. I tried to replicate the similar structure but using a binary file.

```
int main() {

    int searching = 3;
    int counter = 0;
    unsigned char * memblock;
    long long int size;

    //open bin file
    ifstream file;
    file.open("threesData.bin", ios:: in | ios::binary | ios::ate);

    //read bin file
    if (file.is_open()) {
        cout << "it opened\n";
        size = file.tellg();
        memblock = new unsigned char[size];
        file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        file.read((char * ) memblock, size);

        while (file.read((char * ) memblock, size)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                (int) memblock[i];
                if (memblock[i] == searching) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    file.close();
    cout << "The number " << searching << " appears ";
    cout << counter << " times!";
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program it's clear that it opens but it doesn't count the number I'm searching for. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remember, in a binary file, an int will be (likely) 4 bytes, not 1 like in a UTF-8 or ASCII text file. You're going to count anything with a byte of '\x03', which is likely a lot more than you're bargaining for.

Comment: so should I change searching to a uint32_t? or all of my variables should be specified as that type? because I know the the binary file contains 32 bit integers.

Comment: You should cast your input buffer to a different type. Also, I think there are numerous other issues with your code. You seem to call `file.read()` twice before you enter the loop, you open the file to determine the buffer size using the start position (0), and then read in sizes of 0... Choose a sensible value: 4096 or so.

Comment: I'll give you some advice, but you should think this through: read from your buffer, ensure that `size % sizeof(int) == 0`, and then cast to `int* int=
 = (int*)buffer` and iterate `for (size_t i = 0; i < size / sizeof(int); ++i)`; This should help you get going.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I wish I understood it with more clarity.... So i'm dropping the extra file.read() i thought i needed it to start the while loop.... I thought ios::ate allowed for the whole file to be read initially and then file.tellg() would determine its size? .... so for my buffer size I can just pick an arbitrary large number?...

Comment: Actually, @MrM707, you're correct, sorry I missed that. You should still choose a sensible default: buffer sizes of 1 KB to 1 MB tend to work for nearly all use cases.

Comment: as for the additional info I have no idea where Im supposed to put it.  Do i just declare size % sizeof (int) == 0; right under size? ... then my cast should read int* int == (int*)memblock; ?

Comment: Sorry, I felt I had to post a code snippet, I wouldn't accept my answer though and think about **why** this works, and why it's different from what you did.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be thinking this through but here's how I would go about doing it.

1. Initialize a buffer with a sensible size.
2. Cast it to integers, so you can do `array[size_t]` syntax for simpler arithmetic.
3. Open the stream, and read while the stream is valid.
4. Convert the number of read bytes to the number of ints you would expect.
5. Increment the counter for each character you find that is valid.

**Code**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>


bool check_character(int value)
{
    return value == 3;
}


int main(void)
{
    // choose the size, cast a pointer as an int type, and initialize
    // our counter
    static constexpr size_t size = 4096;
    char* buffer = new char[size];
    int* ints = (int*) buffer;
    size_t counter = 0;

    // create our stream, 
    std::ifstream stream("file.bin", std::ios_base::binary);
    while (stream) {
        // keep reading while the stream is valid
        stream.read(buffer, size);
        auto count = stream.gcount();

        // we only want to go to the last valid integer
        // if we expect the file to be only integers,
        // we could do `assert(count % sizeof(int) == 0);
        // otherwise, we may have trailing characters

        // if we have trailing characters, we may want to move them
        // to the front of the buffer....
        auto chars = count / sizeof(int);           // floor division
        for (size_t i = 0; i < chars; ++i) {
            // false == 0, true == 1, so we can just add
            // if the value is 3
            counter += check_character(ints[i]);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Counter is: " << counter << std::endl;

    delete[] buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

As NeilButterworth points out, you could also use a vector. I don't really like this, but "meh".

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/* ellipsed lines */

int main(void)
{
    /* ellipsed lines */
    static constexpr size_t size = 4096;
    std::vector<int> ints;
    ints.resize(size / sizeof(int));
    char* buffer = (char*) ints.data();
    /* ellipsed lines */

    /* ellipsed lines */
    std::cout << "Counter is: " << counter << std::endl;
    // no delete[]
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (stream) {` - that's not how you read a stream in a loop. You need to test the return value of read functions, not simply the stream state. Also, use a vector, not a block of memory allocated with new.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, I could do `if (stream.read(buffer, size))`, but that returns the stream state, but the two are functionally equivalent. The next time the read call happens, `gcount()` will return 0 so the loop won't occur. I did it for readability.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, `istream& read (char* s, streamsize n);` is the function signature, `while (stream) { stream.read(buffer, size)` is just a slightly more verbose and slightly less performant version of `while (stream.read(buffer, size))`. There is, in this context, really no functional difference.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention when you said vector and not string. Deleted that comment. But sure, I could use a vector, it's essentially functionally equivalent. It just makes cleanup a bit nicer. I'll make that edit now. The rest, it is the stream state though. @NeilButterworth

Comment: Thanks Alexander. This was really neat. I didn't think about using a boolean to increment when the value was true that was creative... Also I haven't saw .gcount used on this kind of assignment yet. I think that was what i was looking for to replace getline for a txt file.... I ran this program and it seemed to work it generated a fairly large number and had no problems.... when I evaulate it however, the evaluator gave me a 60% the same I got for my incorrect code. I have no idea what it's looking for but I appreciate your efforts to help me out. You gave me a lot to research.

Comment: @MrM707, you might also have other issues.... If the binary data contains heterogeneous types (it likely does), you can't just increment at intervals of 4: you need some type awareness. I tested this on a flat binary file of 32-bit integers and it works, but it wouldn't work in other cases.

Comment: I see I'll try to research what to do in that situation. I also noticed in your code you don't specify "using namespace std" . This program is meant for an intro class where all of our programs so far utilized it.  I'm going to try to use my initial code and alter it to match somewhat to your code and see what happens

Comment: @MrM707, `using namespace std` is convenient, but generally discouraged because it drags everything from `namespace std` into the current namespace. If you have anything by the name of `string`, `vector`, or something similar, then you have many naming issues. Namespaces exist to solve numerous issues that occurred in C with competing symbols: for simple examples, it's generally not a problem, for large projects, good luck...